# Stored procedure failed in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We kick off a stored procedure through Informatica. 
That Stored procedure worked fine till yesterday but today it did not complete successfully. 
On the Informatica side, we did not see any errors but when I looked at the sql server audit logs, I found the following error.

**“Err 0, Level 16, Server ServerName The statement has been terminated”**

Is this related to timeouts or netowrk related.

Comment: seems that it required too much compute and had terminated the execution, but I can't confirm just with this error message. Try to add more DTU's and monitor the used resources.

Comment: Why tag [tag:sql-server-2012] and [tag:azure-sql-database]? Which are you *actually* using?

Comment: Thank you Thiago, I will try with more DTUs. We are using Azure-SQL-Database. Sorry for the wrong tag.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, did the error solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, you can make it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could check if the you have reach the DTU/resuource limit:

Portal-->SQL Database-->Metrics, you can many metrics about your Azure SQL database resource limit, such as DTU used/max/avg:

[image]

You also could see if the stored procedure or which caused high CPU compute on Portal:

[image]

[image]

You could find the query details:

[image]

And another way, you could follow this document [Monitoring and performance tuning in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview), you could know about more about your Azure SQL database health and 
tuning it.

Hope this helps.